# How to avoid removing the current working directory

Tags: bash, git

Looking at http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/common.c#n579, there does not appear to be a reasonable way to avoid getting a plethora of errors of the form:

shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory

whenever the current working directory is destroyed.  So I've started writing wrappers around git commands which check if I'm about to delete the current working directory and either fail or cd to the top-level working dir before continuing.  This seems like a terrible hack. Is there a reasonable way to tell git *not* to execute a command if doing so would delete the current working directory?  Or is there a reasonable way to tell bash to STFU and stop printing that rather annoying message?  Or perhaps provide a default directory that bash will simply cd to rather than complaining.

Comment: I don't know under what conditions `git` would ever secretly remove by itself a directory, except via the commands `git mv` or `git rm`, and in these cases, you are in the driver's seat anyway. If you are worried only about seeing the error messages, but otherwise be happy with the overall result, you could filter out from stderr lines which contain these texts. But in general, it would help if you told us what you are doing with git, so that this situation occurs.

Comment: @user1934428 I can guess: the current directory is somewhere deep in a repository (not root), the command is `git checkout <other-branch>` and the branch being checked out doesn't have the directory. `git` removes the subtree and oops — there is no longer the current directory.

Comment: Doesn't need to be "deep" in the repo.  The common case I am encountering is indeed a checkout of a branch that does not contain the current working directory.

Comment: You could write a shell function, which saves the current wd, does the cd to the base directory of your repo, then the checkout, and then tries to cd back.